# Edit cell in GtkTreeView (GtkStore) from popup GtkMenu

Tags: gtk

I have GtkTreeView with 3 column packed.
With 'right click' button event a popup menu show with labels.

I want to be emited 'clicked' signal for GtkTreeViewColumn when popup menu label is activate.
For example:

If want to edit frequency cell from 'Frequency' popup menu, cursor to jump at frequency cell in treeview.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor` with the `start_editing` argument set to true:

```
gtk_tree_view_set_cursor(tree_view, path,
                         gtk_tree_view_get_column(tree_view, FREQUENCY_IDX),
                         TRUE);
```

To obtain the path, call `gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos` when handling the right-click event.